# How to convert date string into DateTime format in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm having a string in this format 03/11/2021, how can I convert it into DateTime format. I using showDate Picker to get DOB and the problem I'm facing is with the initialDate that if _dob.text.isNotEmpty then I want the showDatePicker to show the _dob date but it's not working

```
 TextEditingController _dob = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    _dob.text = ""; //set the initial value of text field
    super.initState();
  }

TextFormField(
controller: _dob,
readOnly: true,
onTap: () async {
DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
context: context,
initialDate: _dob.text.isNotEmpty? DateTime.parse(_dob.text):DateTime.now(),
firstDate: DateTime(1975),
lastDate: DateTime.now()
);
if (pickedDate != null) {
String formattedDate =
DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(pickedDate);
setState(() {
_dob.text = formattedDate;
 });
}
},
),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using : `DateTime.parse("your date string");`

if you want some more complex parsing try using 'intl' package
here it is https://pub.dev/packages/intl